# React component not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React Class that's going to an API to get content. I've confirmed the data is coming back, but it's not re-rendering:

```
var DealsList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { deals: [] };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadDealsFromServer();
  },
  loadDealsFromServer: function() {
    var newDeals = [];

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "findDeals", personId: this.props.person.id }, function(deals) {
      newDeals = deals;
    });

    this.setState({ deals: newDeals });
  },
  render: function() {
    var dealNodes = this.state.deals.map(function(deal, index) {
      return (
        <Deal deal={deal} key={index} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="deals">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>Name</td>
              <td>Amount</td>
              <td>Stage</td>
              <td>Probability</td>
              <td>Status</td>
              <td>Exp. Close</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {dealNodes}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

However, if I add a `debugger` like below, `newDeals` are populated, and then once I continue, i see the data:

```
  loadDealsFromServer: function() {
    var newDeals = [];

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "findDeals", personId: this.props.person.id }, function(deals) {
      newDeals = deals;
    });
    debugger
    this.setState({ deals: newDeals });
  },
```

This is what's calling deals list:

```
var Gmail = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="panel">
          <DealsList person={this.props.person} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's because the response from `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is asynchronous; here's the order of operations:

```
var newDeals = [];

// (1) first chrome.runtime.sendMessage is called, and *registers a callback*
// so that when the data comes back *in the future*
// the function will be called
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...}, function(deals) {
  // (3) sometime in the future, this function runs,
  // but it's too late
  newDeals = deals;
});

// (2) this is called immediately, `newDeals` is an empty array
this.setState({ deals: newDeals });
```

When you pause the script with the debugger, you're giving the extension time to call the callback; by the time you continue, the data has arrived and it appears to work.

To fix, you want to do the `setState` call after the data comes back from the Chrome extension:

```
var newDeals = [];

// (1) first chrome.runtime.sendMessage is called, and *registers a callback*
// so that when the data comes back *in the future*
// the function will be called
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({...}, function(deals) {
  // (2) sometime in the future, this function runs
  newDeals = deals;

  // (3) now you can call `setState` with the data
  this.setState({ deals: newDeals });
}.bind(this)); // Don't forget to bind(this) (or use an arrow function)
```

[Edit]

If this doesn't work for you, check out the other answers on this question, which explain other reasons your component might not be updating.

Comment: Duh! I should've known this was the case when the debugger line fixed it. The bind(this) was the thing I missed when I first attempted this. Thanks, great detailed comment!

Answer (score 150):

My scenario was a little different. And I think that many newbies like me would be stumped - so sharing here.

My state variable is an array of JSON objects being managed with useState as below:

```
const [toCompare, setToCompare] = useState([]);
```

However when update the toCompare with setToCompare as in the below function - the re-render won't fire. And moving it to a different component didn't work either. Only when some other event would fire re-render - did the updated list show up.

```
const addUniversityToCompare = async(chiptoadd) =>
  {
      var currentToCompare = toCompare;
      currentToCompare.push(chiptoadd);
      setToCompare(currentToCompare);
  }
```

This was the solution for me. Basically - assigning the array was copying the reference - and react wouldn't see that as a change - since the ref to the array isn't being changed - only content within it. So in the below code - just copied the array using slice - without any change - and assigned it back after mods. Works perfectly fine.

```
const addUniversityToCompare = async (chiptoadd) => {
    var currentToCompare = toCompare.slice();
    currentToCompare.push(chiptoadd);
    setToCompare(currentToCompare);
}
```

Hope it helps someone like me. Anybody, please let me know if you feel I am wrong - or there is some other approach.

Comment: Wow my problem was almost a carbon copy. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, me too.  In ES6 we can use the spread operator to clone the state to prompt React to acknowledge state change: `let newItems = [...items];`

Comment: Yes Meaden, that is correct. I agree. Do you think it makes sense to update my solution post - to include this point as a better way - so people use that as a more generic way around this issue? Glad to be of help.

Comment: haha, carbon copy issue here as well. FUNNY!

Comment: my issue too - thank you

Comment: This was my issue also, although my state is an object so I used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) to create a copy of it with a new ref.

Comment: Carbon copy here as well!... wait, in the end, we always copy the code from someone else, including their problems ;)

Comment: perfect answer, exactly my issue

Comment: Yep, that works like a charm. Now my view started to re-render :D

Comment: Exactly the same problem, but with object. After seeing this answer I solved it using `setState({...state})`.

Comment: Lol, I've been trying to debug this for two hours. Apparently the reference didn't change, so React doesn't re-render. I _almost_ put an ever-increasing key on the component as a hack.

Answer (score 113):

I'd like to add to this the enormously simple, but oh so easily made mistake of writing:

```
this.state.something = 'changed';
```

... and then not understanding why it's not rendering and Googling and coming on this page, only to realize that you should have written:

```
this.setState({something: 'changed'});
```

React only triggers a re-render if you use `setState` to update the state.

Comment: This is the exact issue I was having. It's strange that they don't throw a warning since they throw one when trying to update props.

Comment: @AndrewJM They can't throw a warning. They could if you'd write `this.state = 'something'` because you would be hitting the setter for `state`, but in the example above, the code hits the getter, which returns an object and it then ends up setting a field on an object that is only a copy of the state.

Comment: I have this issue, I update the state once with setState in the end of the Promise Chain. Everything is properly bound and using arrow functions.
I'm getting crazy over here

Comment: @TheBigCheese Better write a (good) question on it. There are people that can help, but not here in the comments of another question.

Comment: @StijndeWitt I logged in to Stackoverflow to upvote your answer. Thanks bro ;D

Comment: Very Important concept for beginners to understand and remember.

Comment: it's not working for me, I have both functional components and Class-Based Components and I'm using useState hook for functional one and this.setState for class based, but in neither case my components do not re-render :(   , and I should mention this : my component's states aren't changing inside of component itself, instead I am passing the handler to change state using props to their children, But I'm sure the handler is getting called and is running ```this.setState``` and is changing the state...

Answer (score 19):

Another oh-so-easy mistake, which was the source of the problem for me: I’d written my own `shouldComponentUpdate` method, which didn’t check the new state change I’d added.

Answer (score 16):

To update properly the state, you shouldn't mutate the array. You need to create a copy of the array and then set the state with the copied array.

```
const [deals, setDeals] = useState([]);
    
   function updateDeals(deal) {
      const newDeals = [...deals]; // spreading operator which doesn't mutate the array and returns new array
      newDeals.push(deal);

      // const newDeals = deals.concat(deal); // concat merges the passed value to the array and return a new array
      // const newDeals = [...deals, deal] // directly passing the new value and we don't need to use push
    
      setDeals(newDeals);
    }
```

Comment: Why direct mutation will not re-render component?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Most likely it is because react only sees the object as a pointer. So React can't recognize that the object has changed before the pointer changes.

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer.

Comment: This works for me. Most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I was calling `this.setState({})` correctly, but I my function wasn't bound to this, so it wasn't working. Adding `.bind(this)` to the function call or doing `this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)` in the constructor fixed it.

Comment: I have this issue. All functions are properly bound in the Constructor.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I was using 'React.PureComponent' when I should have been using 'React.Component'.

Answer (score 2):

I was updating and returning the same object passed to my reducer. I fixed this by making a copy of the element just before returning the state object like this.

```
Object.assign({}, state)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through same issue in React-Native where API response & reject weren't updating states

`apiCall().then(function(resp) {
    this.setState({data: resp}) // wasn't updating
}`

I solved the problem by changing `function` with the arrow function

```
apiCall().then((resp) => {
    this.setState({data: resp}) // rendering the view as expected
}
```

For me, it was a binding issue. Using arrow functions solved it because arrow function doesn't create its's own `this`, its always bounded to its outer context where it comes from

Comment: I have this issue and everything is bound in the constructor and all promises have arrow functions in them. The fields are rendered defaulted at empty or zero (number). When triggering a refresh they blink the values and then go to zero. But thing is, when I key in something in one fill, they all refresh the render and show their values.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into many answers (most of them are correct for their scenarios) and none of them fix my problem I realized that my case is a bit different:

In my weird scenario my component was being rendered inside the state and therefore couldn't be updated.
Below is a simple example:

```
constructor() {
    this.myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this);
    this.changeTitle = this.changeTitle.bind(this);

    this.myMethod();
}

changeTitle() {
    this.setState({title: 'I will never get updated!!'});
}

myMethod() {
    this.setState({body: <div>{this.state.title}</div>});
}

render() {
    return <>
        {this.state.body}
        <Button onclick={() => this.changeTitle()}>Change Title!</Button>
    </>
}
```

After refactoring the code to **not** render the body from state it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is here for similar problem, but using React Functional components rather class components AND also using react reducer, --> Move your api call outside of the reducer. Reducer should never do an api call. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39516485/12121297 for detailed response

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was related to a child component.
In a nutshell:

- Parent component updates the state of an array of objects and
  forwards the updated array to a child component.
- The child component receives the array, creates a copy of if (spread
  operator)  and uses it to update an internal stateful component which
  is supposed to be rendered.
- However, react does not re-render the child component when the update
  occurs in the parent component.

I solved my problem by adding a useEffect hook in the child components.

I still don’t really understand how the state update is handled in my case.

The code is available in my stackblitz repo here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hel9yv?file=src%2FApp.js