# Redux doesn't update component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learing redux with react. I know that to rerender the tree you have to subscribe to some function and dispatch the action, I've done this

```
let render = store => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
}

render(store)

store.subscribe( () => {
    render(store)
})
```

The dispatch works perfectly, I will not show the code because it does not matter in the way that **the problem is about the time when I am truing to load data from the redux store using connect and there is 2 ways, of dispatching to the store**, first:

```
state.articles.push({ title: action.article.title, id: action.article.id })
return state
```

second:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
            articles: state.articles.concat({
                id: action.article.id,
                title: action.article.title
            })
        });
```

And the problem is that only second one works, saying works I mean it updates the LIST component and maps throw redux state

may be need to understand the problem, **LIST** component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { articles: state.root.articles }
}

const ConnectedList = ({ articles }) => (
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    {articles.map(el => (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={el.id}>
        {el.title}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList)
```

Comment: you aren't supposed to directly modify state. Using push on state directly modifies it. instead, use concat and store it in a new variable then return that variable.

Comment: Well, I have read about that but what's problem with the first one, because when I am accesing the state from the **render(store)** using **getState()*** it actually updates the state

Comment: You should read the article in the redux faq: https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data

Comment: When you call `render` you force rendering of the entire react app. Redux-react is much more efficient, it will only rerender the components whose props have changed. But when you use Array.push to mutate state.articles, it has not changed (redux does a shallow compare, so it will not detect a mutation).

Comment: @Håken Lid So you mean that whe n i do push method redux will think that only the array changed and it is not going to update the component, well I will try now to change hole state?

Comment: @Håken Lid Well, that does not help, I created the **a** variable inside of state object and changed it when I was pushing to the array, nothing is changed.... :(

Comment: Don't use `Array.push` in your reducer functions.

Comment: where is your reducer and where are you creating the store.

Comment: I understand it but I still don't understand why at all, I want to know that deeply

Comment: @21x37, This part works fine, so that why i have not added it here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redux: Why is avoiding mutations such a fundamental part of using it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531909/redux-why-is-avoiding-mutations-such-a-fundamental-part-of-using-it)
or
[My Redux state has changed, why doesn't React trigger a re-render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513753/my-redux-state-has-changed-why-doesnt-react-trigger-a-re-render)

Comment: Thanks @Håken Lid, the threads provided by have helped me and I understand the idea of  'not-mutating '!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to use array.push(), because **Redux** need new state, completely new whole state to update the component that you hav esubscribed to, so when we are doing **push** function we are keeping same state, the only thing we change is array inside of its state, so the solution is to create **new object and unite with an old object, that will have the new array :D
Some code:

```
 let absolutelyNewState = Object.assign({}, state, {
            articles: state.articles.concat({
                id: action.article.id,
                title: action.article.title
            })
 })

 return absolutelyNewState
```