# State list change not causing re-render Next.js/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've got the following state:

```js
const [places, setPlaces] = useState(false)
const [selectedPlaces, setSelectedPlaces] = useState([])
```

I asynchronously populate **places** by calling an API that returns an array of objects that looks something like:

```json
[
    {name: "Shop #1", id: 1},
    {name: "Shop #2", id: 2}
]
```

My goal is to render these objects, and have their ID to be added/removed from the **selectedPlaces** state.

Render:

```
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      You have selected {selectedPlaces.length} total places
    </div>
    (places === false)
      ? <div>Loading...</div>
      : places.map(place => { // render places from the places state when loaded
          let [name, id] = [place.name, place.id]
          return <div onClick={() => {
            setSelectedPlaces(selected => {
              selected.push("dummy data to simplify")
              return selected
            })
          }}>{name}</div>
        })

  </div>
)
```

I've removed the key and added dummy data to make the movements simpler.

> **The problem arises when clicking on a div, the "You have selected ... total places" doesn't refresh until I force a re-render using fast refresh or through other methods (using browser/NextJS). Is this correct behaviour? It's as-if the state isn't being changed, but a `console.log` on the `setSelectedPlaces` displays fresh data symbolizing it is being changed.**

I've tried:

- Creating a `useEffect` handler for the `selectedPlaces` state which would `setAmtPlaces` using the length of the selected places. The same issue arises.
- Searched/read-through multiple posts/GitHub issues like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446560/react-setstate-not-updating-state) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937369/react-component-not-re-rendering-on-state-change)
- Replacing the list state with true/false in previous times I've encountered this issue, but I cannot use that approach with this problem since it's a dynamic amount of data being loaded.

Comment: So is it the `selectedPlaces` state update that isn't triggering a rerender? Can you provide a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've a bit more context on what is happening?

Comment: Usually you would use a `useEffect` with dependencies on both of those state variables, so whenever the state values change, it'll force a refresh. Produce a minimal working code sample, and we'll get it working for ya! ;)

Comment: `let [name, id] = [place.name, place.id]` can be written as `let { name, id } = place`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a `{}` wrapper for the ternary operator:

  ```
  {
      places === false 
       ? (...)
       : (....)
  }
  ```
- `push` mutates the state. Use spread or `concat` in `setSelectedPlaces`

  ```
  setSelectedPlaces(selected => 
    selected.concat("abc")
  )
  ```
- `let [name, id] = [place.name, place.id]` can be change to `let { name, id } = place`

Here's a snippet:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([
      { name: "Shop #1", id: 1 },
      { name: "Shop #2", id: 2 }
  ])
  const [selectedPlaces, setSelectedPlaces] = useState([])
  
  const onPlaceClick = id => setSelectedPlaces(state => state.concat(id))
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div> You have selected {selectedPlaces.length} total places </div>
      { (places === false)
        ? <div>Loading...</div>
        : places.map(({ id, name }) => 
            <div onClick={_ => onPlaceClick(id)}>{name}</div>
          )
      }
      <span>{selectedPlaces.join()}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```